# cmake and a folder with the source

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

```
-project
--sourсes
--CmakeList.txt
```

CmakeList.txt to have a repetition:

```
add_executable(Project1 ${SOURCE_FILES}
    sourсes/File1.cpp sourсes/File1.h
    sourсes/File2.cpp sourсes/File2.h
    ...
)
```

All sources lie in the folder "sourсes", which is not a subproject, modules, etc.

How to avoid repetition "sourсes" in "add_executable"?

I would like to be able to write:

```
add_executable(Project1 ${SOURCE_FILES}
    File1.cpp File1.h
    File2.cpp File2.h
    ...
)
```

---

I found this an example:

```
add_sources(PREFIX foo
    ROOT_DIR "sources"
        source_one.cpp
        source_two.cpp

    ROOT_DIR "other/sources"
        source_three.cpp
        source_four.cpp
)

add_executable(foo ${foo_SOURCES})
```

But "add_sources" is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add subdirectories with there own cmakelist.txt.

```
-project
--CmakeList.txt
--sourсes
---CmakeList.txt
```

So in your root cmakelist.txt would look like.

```
add_subdirectory(source)
```

The file ./source/cmakelist.txt would look like

```
set(source_path     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(sources
     ${source_path}/File1.cpp
     ${source_path}/File1.h
     ${source_path}/File2.h
     ${source_path}/File2.h
     ...
)

add_executable(foo ${sources})
```

In this way you could add as many subdirectories as you want without polluting  the root cmakelist.txt.

Comment: I would not use another CmakeList.txt and add_subdirectory, because it is not a subproject.

Comment: The most correct option would be to place cmakelist.txt in "source" folder, but then clion cannot find cmakelist.txt

Comment: @tepesozebe In this case it would be an overkill. But as always if you decide to extend your project just by an own library you doesnt need to restructure anything.

Comment: @tepesozebe your second comment answered why its clean to add_subdirectory ... that doesn't mean always that it is a subproject just a subdictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
set(SOURCES
    File1.cpp File1.h
    File2.cpp File2.h
    ...
)

set(SOURCES_ABS "")

foreach(file IN LISTS SOURCES)
    list(APPEND SOURCES_ABS sources/${file})
endforeach()

add_executable(Project1 ${SOURCES_ABS})
```